# Why would someone want to use Pot of Desires, other than to draw 2 cards?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Pot of Desires](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Pot_of_Desires) allows you to banish the top 10 cards of your deck, facedown, and then draw 2 cards.

*Why would someone do this? Is gaining 2 cards worth it?*

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32511/why-is-pot-of-greed-banned

Comment: " Is gaining 2 cards worth it?" Well, one net card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why would someone do this? Is gaining 2 cards worth it?

*Exactly*.

**Banishing 10 cards face down is the trade-off for drawing 2 cards; it's up to you** (or the deck builder) **to determine if this trade-off is worth it.**

Having a card that just lets you draw 2 cards would be too broken. Such effect should have a trade-off to make it more balanced, and that is why this card requires banishing 10 cards.

In theory, no one wants to banish 10 cards *facedown*, because as they are facedown you can't recover them by any means (at least as far as I  know, as you don't know what card it is).

However, in practice, drawing 2 cards may be worth it, and even decisive for the game result.

Comment: "Having a card that just lets you draw 2 cards would be too broken." More accurately, it *was* too broken - that was Pot of Greed.

Comment: I recall there only being a tiny few cards that interact with banished face down cards. Not worth putting in a deck alongside desires alongside whatever you're playing

Comment: @ConMan precisely. A modern card with such effect should have a trade-off, otherwise it will end banned

Comment: Right. Suppose you know that your opponent is going to win unless you can draw a specific card from your deck. Sure, by playing this card, you banish 10 cards, but you have a chance at not losing. By not playing the card, you guarantee a loss for yourself. It's pretty clear that at least in some circumstances, the card can be advantageous.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Eater Of Millions on the field, that gives him +1000 Attack AND you gain 2 cards in your hand.

Comment: Similarly, there are a few other cards that specify that they work with cards that were banished face-down, along with some cards that only care about the number of banished cards (and thus don't care whether the cards were banished face-up or face-down), which can benefit from Desires' cost.  It's a risky play nonetheless, though.

Comment: The rogue strategy of Gren Maju beatdown has been using Pot of Desires and Gizmek Orochi to create a field of large monsters and a large banish pile to boost the attack of Gren Maju Da Eiza and Eater of Millions. It has done well in a number of tournaments last year.

Answer (score -2):

Also if you use it together with [Soul Absoprtion](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Soul_Absorption) you gain 5000 Health pretty sure there are more cards like this

Answer (score -4):

Because Pot of Greed is banned.

But yeah, by playing 3 copies of your combo pieces you'll mitigate the downside, Upstart Goblin was limited for just drawing 1 card, and it increase your opponent's lifepoints. I'm considering adding desires to my deck because when I was playing with my brother I kept bricking, but if I just had more cards on the same turn rather than using what I had to keep myself alive I might have won.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit confusing. You can [edit] your answer to make it more clear why someone might use Pot of Desires. For example, you mention Upstart Goblin but don't really explain the comparison between that card and Pot of Desires.